# Command is Not Interpreting in Java

Tags: java, shell, process, runtime

I have this block;

```java
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec("bash -c \"mkdir .typo && mkdir .typo/lib && mkdir src/ && mkdir bin/ && ln -sFf .typo/lib lib && mkdir .typo/runtime && touch src/main.typo && echo \"@include !main\n\ndef main(str[255] args) {\n    std:out(\"Hello, world!\");\n\n    return 0;\n}\n\" >> src/main.typo\"");

try {
    process.waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {
    System.exit(130);
}
```

And when I execute it, nothing happens. It sometimes happens but mostly it doesn't works. I also checked file system and there is nothing different too.

( InterruptedException is imported with `import java.lang.InterruptedException`. )

I tried and error is;

```java
.typo: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
.typo: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: What do you mean 'nothing happens'? None off the directories get created? An exception is thrown? Please explain exactly what happens.

Comment: Yeah no directories created and there is no exceptions thrown.

Comment: What is `-p` for?

Comment: At first glance, this could be an escaping problem. The `"` in front of `@import` is ending the command.

Comment: I tried `mkdir -p` nothing changed.

Comment: I did `\"` to `"` that front of `@import`, I think its not the problem

Comment: I think I need to rewrite this in Python. Executing system command in Java has problems.

Comment: This escapes it for the Java world but not inside the bash command.

Comment: Oh right, so I need to put `\\\"`? @Matt

Comment: Try with single quotes for the command: `bash -c ' ... '`

Comment: I did `\\\"`, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line with [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_injection_in_Java), I made this to help in making commands more readable and also retrieving their output (once executed).

```
public class SafeShellExecution {

    
    public String Execute(String[] command) {
        
        StringBuilder strAppend = new StringBuilder();
        
        try {
                String line;
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    strAppend.append(line);
                }
                in.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logging.LogException(ex);
        }
        
        return strAppend.toString();
    }

}
```

And then define the command cleanly:

```
    public static final String[] GetIPAddress = {
        "/bin/sh",
        "-c",
        "ifconfig | grep -v '127.0.0.' | grep -i 'inet ' | awk {' print $2 '} | paste -sd ','"
    };
```

And then execute:

```
SafeShellExecution.Execute(GetIPAddress);
```

Comment: Let me try it. Looking good and useful.

Comment: I tried and... Nothing changed.

Comment: Oh wait, I added `/usr/bin/bash` and `-c` to start of array and it worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the stderr output in order to diagnose what your command is doing:

Add:

```
        InputStream is = process.getErrorStream();
        System.out.println(IOUtils.toString(is));
```

after you create the process.

IOUtils is from:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

The current output is:

```
.typo: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
.typo: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't ( Can't :P ) use Maven so I import packages by source and I already had Apache Commons imported to project. Anyways I replaced `\"` with `\\\"` so now it's also `\"` in BaSH!

Comment: Hopefully this will help with any future issues.

Comment: Yep, I'm sure it'll help. Thank you! By the way I'm sorry I can't upvote because of my reputation points.

Comment: @maDeveloper Java will just execute the command as you write it. You need to first have a working bash-command, then escape it properly (bash-style) on the command line (try it there). And then port it to Java and escape it again there (Java-style).

Comment: Oh ok, thank you again and again.